# Make HLOOKUP not match a substring, like Kansas in Arkansas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a simple formula.

```
=HLOOKUP(A18,Lists!B1:Y7,2,FALSE)
```

I was happy to get it to work but realized one fatal error. I have a section called Arkansas and a section called Kansas. Arkansas has the name Kansas built in and the hlookup is looking for the first value that meets the criteria. How do I make it look for the exact name, not just if it can find within the words?

A18 has either Kansas or Arkansas depending on user selection. The lists range has the state names. The 2 is where is the next item after the names. I thought False would fix this issue but it didn't.

Any help would be great appreciated. I'm sure it's something easy. Thanks!

Comment: I have tested this and the with Excel 2010 the `FALSE` does force exact match though it is not case sensitive. I placed "Arkansas" before and in absence of "Kansas" and it did NOT return the corresponding value of "Arkansas". If "Kansas" was present it returned the value for that entry and if it wasn't the formula returned `#N/A`. Can you please recheck the value that is being returned and confirm it is not correct? Can you also detail what error or value you are getting in return. Regards,

Comment: You're right. After looking into it more, it does seem to be a much deeper issue. I'm such a do-do. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll give you props. I needed to add FALSE to my formulas. I'm embarrassed. Basically, I had another field that used VLOOKUP VLOOKUP(A28,Data!B2:I17,2,FALSE that I hadn't typed "FALSE" so it was finding the first match. But I wasnt looking at that formula because I didn't think it was the problem.

Comment: It's always the little details that get us :). No worries, glad we identified the issue. Cheers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested this with Excel 2010 the FALSE does force exact match though it is not case sensitive. I placed "Arkansas" before and in absence of "Kansas" and it did NOT return the corresponding value of "Arkansas". If "Kansas" was present it returned the value for that entry and if it wasn't the formula returned #N/A. Regards,

Comment: After looking into it more, it does seem to be a much deeper issue. I'm such a do-do. I needed to add FALSE to my other formulas which were the ones causing the issue. Thank you for your help!